# trailing spaces when copying text from vim session in one server to vim session in another server

Tags: cut-copy-paste, ssh

I have two windows open in `tmux`(version 2.3). In first `tmux` window I have a SSH session to `server1` and in second `tmux` window I have a SSH session to `server2`. In `server1` I opened a shell script with `vim script.sh` and selected a part of the script with mouse and paste it to `vim` open in `server2` with middle mouse button. This caused lot of trailing spaces for each line:

[image]

However, when I open `script.sh` in `server1` with `vim -u NONE script.sh`(or with `cat script.sh` or `less script.sh`) and select the same text area and past it to `vim` in `server2`, then trailing spaces are not added:

[image]

This made me think that something in my `.vimrc` causes this behavior. My `.vimrc` is following:

```
set relativenumber
set number
syntax on
set hls
set background=dark
set hidden
set listchars=tab:▸\ ,eol:↲,trail:·
highlight NonText guifg=#054a59
highlight SpecialKey guifg=#4a4a59
set noexpandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set colorcolumn=81
  filetype on
  filetype plugin on
  filetype indent on
  autocmd FileType cpp setlocal ts=8 sts=8 sw=8 noexpandtab
  autocmd FileType * set formatoptions-=c formatoptions-=r formatoptions-=o
  autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.bash set filetype=sh
endif
```

I tried to turn every possible option off(for example `set syntax=`, `set hidden!`, `set colorcolumn=`, etc), but this did not help.

I know that copying and pasting from terminal screen is not reliable, but is there some clever workaround for this?

Comment: `vim -u NONE` also takes out plugins. So if it's not in your `vimrc` there could be a plugin causing it.

Comment: @Tumbler41 I'm not sure it is because of plugins because if I start `vim` in `server1` with `vim --noplugin script.sh`(skips loading plugins, but settings in `.vimrc` are loaded), execute `:set relativenumber!` and `:set number!` and copy tect to `vim` in `server2`, then trailing spaces are added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior was caused by `colorcolumn` option. I started to use [quoteplus register](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/accessing-the-system-clipboard-from-vim/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are running it on `xterm` - one workaround is to use its option to trim trailing spaces from everything you copy with the mouse:

```
xterm -xrm 'XTerm*trimSelection: true'
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Hi Ben, I get that this was asked 4 years ago. Wrote it in case someone stumbles upon this question looking for a solution - as I have.